# CSS Transitions - Matched Tokens

Tags: ace-editor

I would like to be able to add transitions to the certain text layers when a token match is found.

When I add css transitions, it just pops right in. I'm thinking because it actually getting dumped and rebuilt, it's not actually applying those css tags, therefor it never has a chance to transition.

are there any strategies for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add some code of what you have tried to clarify your question, and so we can take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

css transitions won't work because ace often uses `.innerHtml = ...` to redraw all elements, however depending on the type of the animation you want to do you might be able to find a workaround using `beforeRender` and `afterRender` events on `editor.renderer`